# Why an application hangs

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003

I have a window application developed in C# and c++. It has a client edition and server edition.Client edition installed on XP system connected  with Server edition installed with windows 2003 system. But the UI in the client system most of the time hangs .I dont know whats the reason

So my folder space is the problem? whenever hang happend in client system i checked taskmanager,process tab's memory column ,there i can see my application exe taking largest space

I have done virus scan, forcibly closed hanging application from task manager. but again whenever i start again hang most of the time

**EDIT**

So here my question is any manupulation on host file will make any slow down in client
In server i can see an entry in the host file like shown below
**EDIT**

Do i need to enable any services from MMC i mean services.msc for proper conncetion between client and server , i have started Remoteregistry service now?
Some windows security updates are pending , will it make any problems like flickering like tha?

Comment: Did you write the software,is your UI mufti-threaded?

Comment: we are using STA, even i did endprocess for the my application exe which was using more memory from takmanger . next time when i opened agian that issue coming most of the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use C# but in general, the UI of an application can hang when the UI updating code is not cleanly separated into a thread that is separate from the threads used for network IO (or other non-UI tasks). In such a case, a slow response to a network call can cause the UI to become unresponsive because the network call is blocking the UI thread. This means that UI events (key presses, mouse clicks) are blocked.

IO such as network IO can often be written in blocking or non-blocking styles. Using a non-blocking style might mitigate the effects of not having UI-updating code on it's own thread.

So a combination of a poorly written application and a slow network or misconfigured client (e.g. incorrect address for server) could cause this.

I would say that the UI of a well-written application should not hang unless the CPU is at 100% utilization.

However, this is speculation. The chances of any guess being correct are small. For better answers you may need to provide more details about the application (name, author if retail software) and exactly when and how the UI "hangs".

Comment: i have a question now , i was remotely connecting to a Windows Xp machine, by mistake i closed explorer.exe, suddenly everything gone. Now i dont know how to connect to that machine.When i enterd credntial its showing blank

Comment: @Henric: that's a separate question. If I remember correctly, explorer.exe (not iexplore.exe) runs the Windows desktop, you need to restart it, a reboot is the usual way to do this.

Comment: may be the point you mentioned are correct "o a combination of a poorly written application and a slow network or misconfigured client (e.g. incorrect address for server) could cause this" now i am checking both systems Host file.I will update the question, thanks

Comment: "open Task Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Del or Ctrl+Shift+Esc). In the Task Manager go to File – New Task (Run) – type in explorer and click OK. That will bring the shell back." If you are using RDP you'll need to lookup what keystrokes to use for Ctrl+ALt+Dell on the remote rather than local computer.

Comment: great , now i am checking both systems host file whehter any misconfiguration happened ,i will update my question, thanks