# What are the important things that need to be taken care while setting a network connection between systems?

Tags: networking, performance, lan, hosts-file, windows-server-2003

I have an application which has a client edition(workstation) and server edition(service). The client edition is on Windows XP and the server edition is on Windows Server 2003.  We have a lot of machines running different setups and networks.  The above mentioned client machine application is hanging, only that setup hang-up is there, other than that all of the other systems running on different networks haven't had any issues.

I suspect it will be related to some network issues.  Kindly provide the expected network issues which would lead to an application hanging in a client server environment.  I have heard that "the same network name identfied with multiple IP addresses which may be causing at least some delays in resolving the names or at worst a failure which will cause a hang," is that correct? Any others?

This is some part of the host file taken from Server. Here the troublesome client machine name is `tvr-lzvrts`, but again i can see `lzvrts2`, do i need to move this into comments(#). I can see lot of entries without comments  `mntis        mnefms ht7`

```
192.61.247.204  tvr-lzvrts2 lzvrts2                    # TISSON   
192.61.247.205  ght7                      ht7                       # TISSON  
192.61.247.94   mns6                       mntis        mnefms       # LEVIS
```

**EDIT**

One more thing, I forgot when I asked about some IP address information, the team said they are using the IP addresses as place holders in the `Hosts` file until they have the correct public IP addresses from the customer.  The cables are not connected.  Do I need to disable these ports until they are ready to use the real IP addresses for the customers?

**EDIT**

In the client system, my application takes most of the memory and the CPU usage is around 93%. I confirmed these facts from Task Manager.  I can see a lot of flickering going on my application.

Comment: This question looks remarkably like your earlier question http://superuser.com/q/365976/52492. I suggest you address the reasons why that question was closed. You could consider editing the original question and asking for it to be reopened. Your new  Question's title "Network related problems" is a bit vague.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick before that somebody closed that question, so i thought it will be waste to edit that question. In that answer you gave me some hints like network related issue thats why i made it as an answer and asked a new question

Comment: I closed all application through task manager, did Windows update ,Virus scan everything , then also client system application hangs, i beleive some problems in network, some lan issue or NIC card issue,Any provide me where i need to look

Comment: any more suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using hosts files for resolving host-names to IP-addresses is error-prone
  it is likely that there will be inconsistencies between hosts files on different computers.
  In the longer term it is best to use a local DNS server (using split-DNS so local computers
  can resolve non-local Internet hostnames).
- I would use `ping` to check that `hosts` files are working as expected.
  At the client, open a Command Prompt window and type `ping servername`.
- You can use ping at the server to check the server's hosts file has the
  correct hostname and address for the client **but this is usually uneccessary**.
- You can use a packet-sniffer (such as [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org)) to see
  what your client is sending, and where to. I find the "follow TCP connection"
  feature particularly useful. You'll need a basic understanding of TCP/IP.

Example

```
C:\> ping servername

Pinging servername.example.com [192.61.247.99] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.61.247.99: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.61.247.99: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.61.247.99: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.61.247.99: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.61.247.99:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

- Note that it got the correct IP-address for the name `servername.example.com [192.61.247.99]`.
- Check that the response time is reasonable  -`time<1ms`
- Check that there is no packet loss - `(0% loss)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably  you need to look in to you network,whether all APIs,NIC cards are udated. If the names are not used for resolving then you may need to move to comments. check your logs also

Comment: So you mean i need to move entry "lzvrts2" in to comments?